# Not able to get address using lat and long in iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps

Please can any one help me get the latitude/longitude location of the user. I have tried many things but I'm not able to solve this problem. If anyone has an idea please help me.

I'm a beginner in iPhone so please give brief explanation.

Comment: How do you do that without an iphone?  Use the same method.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean in the browser (not a native application), since you have tagged this question as javascript. You do it via an asynchronous callback:

```
//Function that does something once the device has a location
//May be called repeatedly
function handler(location) {
  var longitude = location.coords.longitude;
  var latitude = location.coords.latitude;
  var accuracy = location.coords.accuracy

  //Do something with them
}

//Register the handler and tell the phone to start finding a location
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handler);
```

It is all part of the HTML5 geolocation stuff, there is a draft [here](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).